# how are larger leadscrews (14mm diameter and up) fixed in place?

Tags: linear-motion, linear-control

So looking at 12mm lead screws and below, it seems like a common method for fixing them in place is to use pillow blocks. The pillow block has set screws which clamp onto the lead screw, and you're all set. However, the common size pillow blocks are 8, 10 ,12, 15, 17, 20mm, etc. So for 12mm and below, it's easy to find a pillow block for them.

for 14mm and larger, I can't seem to find pillow blocks in that size. Is there another common practice that's used for these larger sizes? I could imagine a bushing could be insert into the pillow blocks of a larger size... but then I haven't been able to find bushings that would fit there either.

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this... I just haven't run across it yet. Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe at home in your basement you might use a pillow block, but I don't think you would use something as slip shod as a set screw on an acme leadscrew in industry. Set screw going into an acme thread just sounds like a bad idea to me. I can't see anyone doing that in manufacturing so that might be the reason you can't find a suitable pillow block. I think in industry, machining the end would actually be what is done and looking at the various machine tools in the shop that seems to be true.

Either way, 14mm seems to be an oddball size for acme screws. That can happen; Not everything can be standard so people who want to use it would machine something for the screw, or the end of the screw itself. If you can't machine things then don't use oddball parts.

There are 14mm clamping collars for regular shafts so you could use that and then stick it in a MASSIVE pillow block...if you can find one. Because 14mm shaft collars seem to be 30mm in outer diameter which is also an odd pillow block size. But you could forego the pillow block and just drill holes into the collar and bolt it to the face of something as if it were a flange. Since they are clamping collars they will flex as will any holes on their face holes so drill them large enough for clearance and transfer the holes with locating transfer punches.